# Difference between matlab normrnd() mvnrnd()

Tags: matlab

What is the difference in Matlab if I do:

```
R = mvnrnd(MU,SIGMA)
```

vs.

```
R = normrnd(mu,sigma)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R = normrnd(mu, sigma)` outputs normal random numbers from [**1D** normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) distribution. i.e., for *each element* of the inputs a single output is generated - `R(i)` will be a random scalar from the normal distribution defined by `mu(i)` and `sigma(i)`.

If `sigma` is a scalar rather than vector the same value is used for each element of `R`.

`R = mvnrnd(MU,SIGMA)` outputs random numbers from [**multivariate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) normal distribution. i.e., for each *row* of `MU` and *2D matrix* of `SIGMA` a single row of `R` is generated, where the dimension (`d`, the number of columns) of `R` is the same as the dimension of `MU` and `SIGMA`. `R(i,:)` will be a random vector from the multivariate normal distribution defined by `MU(i,:)` and `SIGMA(:,:,i)`.

if `SIGMA` is a `d`x`d` 2D matrix rather than `d`x`d`x`n` 3D matrix, the same 2D matrix is used for each row of `R`.